# Best practice - REST URI Design for resource identified by two names

Tags: xml, rest, resources, uri

A REST resource should be identified by two names. What is the best practice for this?

My ideas:

```
 .../{id1}-{id2}
 .../{id1}/{id2}
```

An id can consists of numbers, letters and special characters.

First solution:

A problem occurs if one of the ids contains the character `-`. In this case the separation character is not unique.

Second solution:

At just `.../{id1}` will be no resource, is this RESTful?

**Edit:**

The REST resource represents credentials. Credentials are identified by a provider name and the username.

```
 .../Credentials/<ProviderName>;<UserName>
```

I don't want to show at `.../Credentials/<ProviderName>` all credentials of the provider (it wouldn't fits to my XML structure).

**Edit 2:**

At `.../Credentials` all credentials will be showed in XML. A credentials is there represented as a sub element of the XML root element. I want to a create a REST resource structure that is equal to the XML structure. Thus, a sub resource of `.../Credentials` should be directly a certain credentials (and not a set of credentials like all of a provider).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what 2 names means and what these IDs represent ? It would be better if you provide an example to give more context.

Comment: Edited my initial post.

Comment: can you be more specific in what do you want to read for the last url if not is all credentials for the provider?

Comment: Added again some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution `.../{id1}/{id2}` says for me that you have a hierarchy relationship between `id1` and `id2`, which seems to not fix very well your resource design since both
identifiers reference the same resource, as you say. In the other hand, for you first solution `.../{id1}-{id2}` you can use `;` instead `-` to avoid implying hierarchy where none exist
as cited in [Restful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260) so i will go with this:

```
.../{id1};{id2}/
```

Comment: Annotation @Path("{id1};{id2}") seems to doesn't work with Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

REST API must be hypertext-driven, so don't waste your time on URL patterns, because they are not RESTful. A URL pattern implicates tight-coupling between client and server; simply, the client must be aware of how URLs look like and have ability to construct them.

See also this post:

http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Note about credentials; It seems that you are keeping a state between client and server which also violates REST principle: stateless.